# Revoke/Invalidate the oauth2 refresh token generated in a .boto file (gsutil config)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, access-token, boto, gsutil

I'm using a user account to access Google Play Console and get several monthly reporting.
So, I developed a web app to get automatically this reporting (csv files) hosted in a Google Cloud Storage bucket (gs://uri).
For that, a **.boto** file was created using "**gsutil config**" command where I obtained inside a refresh token oauth2 through the user account:

```
[Credentials]

# Google OAuth2 credentials (for "gs://" URIs):
# The following OAuth2 account is authorized for scope(s):
#     https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
#     https://www.googleapis.com/auth/accounts.reauth
gs_oauth2_refresh_token = [*************]
```

This works fine, but (always a but...) I don't know how I can revoke/invalidate this refresh token. I mean, I can generate again a new refresh token with the "**gsutil config**" command but this action is not revoking/invalidating the previous token.
Maybe someone on this planet could help me with this ;)

Many thanks in advance.

R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a request to the URL `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token={token}`.

This is mentioned in Google's documentation on how to use OAuth2 tokens in web services:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke

Comment: Thanks @mhouglum! It worked fine using the HTTP/Rest method: curl -d -X -POST --header "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token={token}